# How to transfer music onto iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, data-transfer

I just got a new MacBook Air and I am trying to transfer my music that I did not buy from iTunes from my old computer onto my new MacBook. I saved my music onto a USB drive but the music won't transfer into my iTunes on my new computer. Please Help!

Answer (score 7):

Within iTunes, select on the "Add to Library" option:

[image]

Then select on the folder containing your music. It may take some time to import, but your music should then be accessible within iTunes.